# New loud single pop/bang from speakers during boot even though headphones are plugged in

Tags: boot, 18.04, sound, headphones, speakers

**Following** a **regular upgrade**:

```
$ sudo apt full-upgrade
```

**To either** `4.15.0-64-generic` **or** `4.15.0-64-generic` I **started** to get this **pop/bang** from my speakers during **boot**, **before** the **Ubuntu splash** screen.

1. It's only ever a single pop/bang, but it's loud and annoying and it wasn't there before.
2. The noise comes from my speakers even though my headphones are plugged in (no pop/bang from headphones)

Subsequent kernel updates have not resolved the issue.

There are **no other sound issues** or speaker/headphones crossover issues detected.

Any advice on troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated.